# Delete array object when value is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I've the following array and I want to delete just the entry where the **name** is empty like the first and the third object,how should I do it efficentlly?

```
var myopj =[
    { "Name": "", "Value": "" }
    { "Name": "aaa", "Value": "bbb" },  
    { "Name": "", "Value": "" }
];
```

I saw some example in SO like but in my case it's little bit more complicated, I need to delete name where the value is `""`

```
arr.splice( arr.indexOf( "name" ), 1 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
myopj = myopj.filter(function(o){return o.Name});
```

Struictly speaking this creates a new array and assigns it to your `myopj` variable, rather than deleting items from the old one, but is probably the simplest way to achieve what you need.

If your array is very large and you really do want to delete items you will need to use a `for` loop and use `splice` to chop out the ones you don't need, but I think using `filter` is nicer.

Comment: Thanks but I need the opposite ,just to keep in the array values where name is not empty ,i.e. just the third entry...

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`jQuery.grep()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to filter the array using some criteria:

```
var myopj = [
    { "Name": "", "Value": "" },
    { "Name": "aaa", "Value": "bbb" },
    { "Name": "", "Value": "" }
];
var myopj_copy = $.grep(myopj, function(item, index) {
    return item.Name !== "";
});

// myopj_copy is [{"Name":"aaa","Value":"bbb"}]
```

This function returns a copy of array, original array remains unchanged.